# Как предотвратить показ закэшированной страницы при нажатии на кнопку "НАЗАД" в браузере?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

В кратце. Пользователь залогинился. Гулял по сайту. Затем вышел (нажал выход).

Его кинуло на страницу авторизации. Это нормально. Но когда пользователь жмет стрелку "НАЗАД" в браузере, то ему открываются ранее просмотренные страницы сайта (где он был залогинен).

Получается его информация в опасности и может быть доступна третьим лицам.

Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на кнопку "НАЗАД" страница обновлялась и соотвественно возвращалась на авторизацию.

Comment: а как так выходит, вы  не делаете destroy_session ? Вы же на сервере проверяете сессию? Что то типа такого ` if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) : 
      header("Location: login.php");  `

Comment: Я не использую сессии. Только cookie.

Comment: а вы проверяете наличие куки когда заходите на страницу? И вы удаляету куку когда делаете layout?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, все у vKs правильно. Браузер хранит цепочку перемещений по страницам и при нажатии Назад не запрашивает страницу у сервера, а достает ее из своего кеша.

Comment: Да кука проверяется и удаляется после выхода.

Comment: @Visman, а как же тогда обойти этот кеш? Запреты на кеширование не помогают, так как браузерам плевать на запреты

Comment: Как вариант аякс запрос на проверку авторизации

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick Аякс запрос не сработает, так как страница загружает кеш и больше никаких скриптов.
Для этого нужно сделать обход кеша и заставить страницу изначально загружаться с сервера. Вот только как это реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Запрет кеширования(http)

Изначально страницы нужно отдавать с заголовком:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store
```

Каждый их этих атрибутов заголовка предназначен для запрета кеширования.

#### Meta-теги(html)

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

#### Очистка истории(js)

*Очень ненадёжно, код после `history.go` никто не хочет выполнять)*

```
history.go(-(history.length-1)); 
location.href='/login';
```

Comment: Cache-Control: где его и как вставить?

Comment: И очистка истории не работает

Comment: Большое спасибо. Помог запрос header('Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store');